# VNC connection drops when i bridge wifi with ethernet on Windows 7

Tags: wifi, ethernet, raspbian-stretch, vnc, bridge

. Installed Raspbian stretch on Raspberry Pi B+ (v1.2). I am bridging the connection between my wifi and LAN.

- RPI IP: 169.254.198.47
- LAN IP on PC, Windows 7: 169.254.34.239

The VNC connection drops as soon as i bridge the wifi with ethernet on which is connected my RPI

Comment: Your bridge is on Windows 7? This isn't really a question belonging to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I also tried sharing using the internet sharing property(Network and sharing center-> change adapter settings->(choose wifi adapter)right click to properties-> On sharing tab->Enable sharing with LAN), but i get the same result, i don't really think its an issue of the bridge.But i'll be glad to understand my misunderstanding, that's why i am asking for explanation. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what to explain? We are on Raspberry Pi. Your bridge is on Windows 7. I don't  know anything about Windows. I'm using Linux. I assume the network connection on the raspi is working. May you ask this question in a Windows forum?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just understood that i can't use the same medium for two different things at the same time. It won't go.

Comment: Unclear answer to an unclear question.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bridge [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address).

Obviously neither of your interfaces has an actual IP address.

Comment: I also tried sharing in normal for as shown in my last two posts, and i have the same issue. i do admit that before bridging both interfaces have IPs, and after bridging only the bridge has, but i thought this is the way bridges work. I believe it has to do with ports.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is fairly simple.

You have an interface up, and establish a VNC connection across it.  Then you try to make this interface part of a bridge.  The first thing that happens is that the interface goes down.  At this point, any connection across the interface is terminated.  Then the bridge is formed, and brought up.  At this point, the bridge may or may not have the same address as the original interface, but the connection that was there is already gone.

The secret: configure the bridge in `/etc/network/interfaces`, and let the boot process bring it up.

A related secret: Run a DHCP server somewhere (the PI can do this well, as can most internet routers) to assign private use addresses to all the machines.

Comment: Please note that the bridge isn't on the Raspberry Pi so there is no need to configure anything on the RasPi. The bridge is on a MS Windows device.

Comment: Interesting.  Then how  do you have a connection between the PC and the PI **before** you bridge the networks?  Or are both devices on the LAN?  If the issue is  that starting a bridge on a third device on the LAN disconnects VNC, then I suggest examining the IP addresses of the first two before and after the bridge starts.  And given the 169.254.*.* addresses, a significant change in network topology like starting a bridge necessitates revalidating all the addresses.  That could take down a link as well.

Comment: I don't know, it's not a problem of a Raspberry Pi.